# getDistance() method is not working in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x, game-physics, physics-engine

//-Joint creation.

```
auto fixedjointleft = PhysicsJointDistance::construct(upperbody, leftbody, upperbody->getPosition(),leftbody->getPosition() );

auto fixedjointright = PhysicsJointDistance::construct(upperbody, rightbody, upperbody->getPosition(), rightbody->getPosition());

auto jointgear = PhysicsJointGear ::construct(leftball->getPhysicsBody(), rightball->getPhysicsBody(), 200.0,4.0);
```

//--Adding into PhysicsWorld

```
physics_world->addJoint(jointgear);
physics_world->addJoint(fixedjointleft);
physics_world->addJoint(fixedjointright);

CCLOG("  distance = %f", fixedjointleft->getDistance());
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how getDistance() method is not working. Is it returning values that don't seem correct? Is it crashing your application? Is it hanging? Thanks!

Comment: It's crashing the app!